# The directory react-app contains files that could conflict: package.json

Tags: reactjs

I entered this command to the terminal:

`create-react-app react-app`

And I get this error:

`The directory react-app contains files that could conflict: package.json
Either try using a new directory name, or remove the files listed above`

Please help!

Comment: type `rm -rf react-app` and rerun your command OR type `create-react-app YOURNAME`

Comment: Thank you @Paulquappe it works

Answer (score 3):

Temporarily move the files VScode complaints about to another folder (in your case package.json)

Then  `create-react-app react-app`

Bring back the files

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows, just go to the Users folder and you'll see that a folder of your project would have been created. Just delete the project folder you want to recreate. And it's done.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2022, this happens if you put the project and the solution in the same folder when creating a new project.

**SOLUTION**
Uncheck the box

[Uncheck the box in visual studio for standalone react app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlcrb.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but with a .json file pre-built with new folder I make with VSCODE...deleting the file fixes this issue. Hope this helps someone.

P.S.
React package includes a .JSON file and VS code for some reason has a default .JSON file on new folders(yet to figure that out). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the README.md
It's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove-Item : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'rf'.
At line:1 char:4

- rm -rf react-app
- 

```
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

Comment: Looks like you're having an error. If you have an issue you should create a new question instead of posting it as an answer on a related issue.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35443747)